# Command-line (cmd) command to lock a windows machine

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to lock a Windows XP machine via the command line?  The `shutdown` command doesn't have an option for it.

Comment: From a Remote Desktop session, you should be able to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> to show the Windows Security screen (where you can lock your workstation, restart, etc.). In Vista or above, you can also select "Windows Security" from the Start Menu. ![Windows Security menu item](http://i32.tinypic.com/5vfqv.png)

Comment: [psshutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) has a `-l` parameter to lock your workstation.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

I've been warned that this isn't recommended (except by [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750823.aspx)). The warnings are also centered around the command's close relative, ExitWindowsEx (Which shuts down the computer). I've never had any issues with it, but [YMMV](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/your_mileage_may_vary).

> **Schlump**: The poodle-monkey may be right. The legend warns that the code is powerful and dangerous.
>   **Nudar**: My God. We'd better use it only three or four times. Six, max.
>   **Nibbler**: But even a single use could shatter the universe!
>   **Nudar**: Got it. Two or three times.

([Source](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript:Bender's_Big_Score_Part_1))

Comment: For a while I had a webpage on my computer that, if visited, would invoke this command (on my computer, not the visitors). It was basically a remote lock for my computer, for when I forget to lock it when I leave the house and realize that my brother is visiting.

Comment: Calling functions like this using rundll32 is really not recommended. For more information, see http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx -- scroll a little down to the "rundll32" section.

Comment: I've never had a problem with it, and it still works in Windows 7 (one could presume that it wasn't problematic enough to fix). Either way, it's still the only command line option to lock the computer (short of installing a program to do it for you).

Comment: @TuxRug I've included it in the source link. It's from the Futurama movie Bender's Big Score. Nibbler is the poodle-monkey.

Comment: But *why* isn't it recommended?

Comment: Use `tsdiscon` instead to lock the workstation

Comment: @AnthonyW: [`tsdiscon`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490805.aspx) seems to log out of the session, not lock it.

Comment: I recognize that this is an older question, but I just found that Microsoft has an article documenting the use of rundll32, so this does appear to be the recommended method:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/changing-computer-state?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Works for me! I needed a way to remotely lock my remote workstation that is otherwise unlockable due to [my Computa Pranksta device keeping it awake](https://www.amazon.com/Programmable-Jiggler-50-Settings-Makes-Hacked-Randomly-Gibberish/dp/B06ZYZ2GTB/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=ll1&tag=wwwel-20&linkId=fc2cb611974b74ee5226deac2c617932) so it won't sleep (so I can remote in), and the command above works!

Answer (score 15):

If you have access to Visual Studio's C++ compiler here's the (extremely complicated) source:

```
//
//LockWorkStation.cpp
//
//Locks the console.
//
//To compile (VC++ 2003, on one line):
//
//      cl.exe /W4 LockWorkStation.cpp /link /RELEASE /OPT:REF /OPT:NOWIN98
//                  /ENTRY:mainStartup /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE kernel32.lib
//

#if !defined(_WIN32_WINNT) || (_WIN32_WINNT < 0x0500)
    #undef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500 
#endif
#include <windows.h> 

void mainStartup(void)
{
    LockWorkStation(); 
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Comment: I compiled this with VS2015 using this command: `cmd /s /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64 & cl.exe /W4 LockWorkStation.cpp /link /RELEASE /ENTRY:mainStartup /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE kernel32.lib user32.lib"`

Comment: Thanks this is fantastic! I think it might just be the smallest Windows EXE I've ever made.
Here's a great icon for it https://www.iconarchive.com/show/soft-scraps-icons-by-hopstarter/Lock-Lock-icon.html

Answer (score 6):

Note that in Windows Vista/7, you can use the command `tsdiscon` to disconnect a Remote Desktop session/lock your workstation.

If you use the `rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation` command in a Remote Desktop session (in Windows 7/Vista), the session will continue, but you will just see the lock screen in the Remote Desktop window.

Comment: [TSDISCON has been introduced in Windows 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321705) just checked, and it is available in windows XP as well.

Comment: [Don't use rundll32.exe with LockWorkStation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx), it will mess with the call stack, and leave that mess in your session.

Comment: This is the [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20150405214457/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx) link for that article.

Answer (score 4):

Since it's not recommended to run LockWorkStation via rundll32.exe, another solution is to use [Wizmo](http://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm). Just run:

```
wizmo lock
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Wizmo](https://www.grc.com/wizmo/wizmo.htm) tool recommended in other answer is pretty old and not being updated / maintenanced anymore.

I suggest using the [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) tool instead. It's a lightweight and versatile command-line utility for Windows that allows you to do a ton of pretty cool and useful tasks without displaying any user interface.

To lock the computer, just run:

```
nircmd.exe lockws
```

Answer (score 2):

For running on a scheduler or after some minutes you leaved computer you can use
`timeout /t 36000 /nobreak & rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation`
create a `.bat` file put it in scheduled task, put the trigger run on idle.

You can change `/t xxx`. how much you need to wait.

Thanks to Kevin, he used the command for shutdown, thats:
`timeout /t 36000 /nobreak & shutdown /h /f`

Comment: Just so you aren't disappointed if you do not get a response, you should know you have answered a question which has an accepted answer and is 5 years old. You have not done anything wrong. Just wanted you to know.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working bat command for Remote PC

```
@echo off
COLOR 3E
@echo Lock Remote PC
SET /P PC=ıp or Host Name: 
\\%PC%\c$\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Answer (score 1):

I set my computer to automatically logon, immediately run "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation" and then start loading apps (single .CMD file in my startup folder).

Works nicely.  When I need to reboot and I'm at a breaking point I restart the computer, go on a break, etc and when I get back I unlock my computer.  Apps all loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Use Powershell and Windows API:

```
$code = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void LockWorkStation();
'@
$winApi = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name WinAPI -Namespace Extern -PassThru
$winApi::LockWorkStation()
```

Answer (score -3):

You can also do this from a local machine to lock a remote workstation by using a UNC path:

```
\\computername\c$\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Getting access denied with Windows 7 workstations, but works with Windows XP.

Comment: This will just run the rundll32.exe binary on your local workstation from the remote workstation's disk, and then lock your local workstation.

Comment: This locks the machine on which it is running

Answer (score -7):

On Windows Server 2012 press: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: This isn't a *command-line command*.