# Launch AutoStart programs before login

Tags: windows-7, boot, login

When I turn on my computer, I usually leave it to boot for a few minutes before I come back. However, when I get back I have to log in and then wait for all my start up programs to load. Is there anyway to have those programs load at the log in screen (I only have one account)? I am running Win7 x64.

Comment: Why don't you use the hibernation feature of Windows? You never logout. You login once, start all the programs you want, and you're done with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to load your start up programs is to log on with your user account. If you want to automatically log in when your computer starts, there are instructions here:

[How to enable autologon in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/88263/how-to-enable-autologon-in-windows-7/88264#88264)

If you are concerned with security (I would be), you can add a startup program that will lock the screen:

[Command-line (cmd) command to lock a windows machine](https://superuser.com/questions/21179/command-line-cmd-command-to-lock-a-windows-machine/21180#21180)

That way, your computer will start, your user account will log on, and the screen will lock. You will still have to enter your password when you get back to your computer, but your start up items will have loaded.

Comment: There are some ways to start program before log on... I've seen such programs, but I don't know how they work.