# Windows 10: How to Lock (not sleep) laptop on lid close?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, lock-screen, lid

If my laptop is plugged in I want closing the lid to automatically *lock* the computer, *without* putting it to sleep.  I don't see an option to do this in Power Options:

[image: Power screen]

Is there a hack to achieve this?

Comment: This is generally a bad idea: your laptop dissipates a good deal of heat through the keyboard, and if you leave the computer running with the lid closed, you risk overheating things.

Comment: @Mark: ...and yet you can set it to keep running full blast when you close the lid, _without_ frying anything.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no built-in function to achieve this. But you can do this using a third party tool.

One of them is [LapLock](https://github.com/dechamps/laplock). This program is a lightweight (<50KB), open source tool and it's developed by [Etienne Dechamps](https://superuser.com/users/8695/etienne-dechamps).

Steps...

1. Download the program - https://github.com/dechamps/laplock/releases
   <sup>(Download the latest laplock.exe release)</sup>
2. Open the Windows Startup folder by using this run command - '`shell:common startup`'
3. Add laplock.exe to your Startup folder.

You can also use [Lid Lock](https://download.cnet.com/Lid-Lock/3000-2094_4-76464070.html) to do this.

Comment: thanks, this implementation pretty much sums up the answer by mazunki, uses GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE

Answer (score 9):

**Two steps:**

- Capture the close lid event.
- Trigger a lock-screen event.

See: [Capturing laptop lid closing event in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37179068/6278788), and [Command-line (cmd) command to lock a windows machine](https://superuser.com/a/21180/364367).

From those sources, we can use `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` and `GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE` to detect the trigger, and run:

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

from the command line to send a lock screen request to the machine.

I don't know what compilers you have available, or what languages you know, but this information should help you set up a program to do it for you.

I don't use Windows myself, so I can't build or test it for you.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is simple, in options --> accounts --> Sign-in options: Require sign-in = Every Time

[image]

Comment: I do not see a "Require sign-in" option in that section.  Below "Picture Password" I have "Dynamic Lock" ... "Privacy" ... but no *Require sign-in*.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely because of the Extended Display Option set for the Monitor. Set the display only to Monitor, it should work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little more?